# Ionic 2 : Take picture like a scan

Tags: android, ios, cordova, angular, ionic2

I develop an app with Ionic 2 and cordova and I want to have the same effect I already found in apps like "Tiny Scanner", "Clear Scanner" or "Fast Scanner" in the google play store.

I want to know if exist a cordova plugin to do something like that when I take a picture in my application ?

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Check http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

Comment: this is super vague. instead of listing other applications, rather specifically state what functionality you want